# SQL Select where column contains 1 value in set of words

Tags: sql, select

I need a select which would return row if column A of that row contains any word from a list of words which get from user input

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE ColumnA CONTAINS ANY 'list of word'
```

Since the list of words has an unknown number of words, I store the whole list in the same string. each word can be separated with "_", "-" or white space.

Comment: What database you are using ?

Comment: Im using SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this if you are using oracle :

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ColumnA in (select upper(regexp_substr('word1- 
word2-word3','[^-]+',1,level)) from dual
connect by upper(regexp_substr('word1-word2-word3','[^-]+',1,level)) is 
not null)
```

If you are using "_" then replace the hyphen with underscore is regexp_substr parameter.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep that in mind. But I'm currently stuck with SQL server

Answer (score 0):

I've came up with this solution:

```
SELECT *
from TableA tb 
RIGHT JOIN STRING_SPLIT ( 'list of words' , 'seperator' ) v on tb.ColumnA = v.value
WHERE tb.ColumnA IS NOT NULL
```